# Connection Reset by Peer with Python module urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, google-custom-search

What I'm tryng to do is to download images through Google Custom Search API using Python. It's my first time and maybe I'm making some banal error catching exceptions with Python.

It all works fine  even when I get into some error which is not 10054 Connection Reset By Peer. The code is something like this, I've just taken out the useless part:

```
try: 
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(myUrl['link'],str(count)+'.jpg')
except URLError as e:
    print(e.reason)
```

Sometimes it happens that connection is reset by peer and the console shows this error.

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(myUrl['link'],str(count)+'.jpg')
File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 210, in urlretrieve
   block = fp.read(bs)
File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 503, in read
   return super(HTTPResponse, self).read(amt)
File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 542, in readinto
   n = self.fp.readinto(b)
File "C:\Python33\lib\socket.py", line 297, in readinto
   return  self._sock.recv_into(b)
   ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   Press any key to continue . . .
```

Now I'm not really interested in make that URL work, but I just want my loop to keep going and not to stop. How can I catch that exception?

Edit:

I also noticed that sometimes the code correctly catches the error and `print(e.reason)` correctly outputs `[WinError 10054]` without stopping the loop. That's very strange.

Comment: You know you can copy text from cmd windows? No need to paste screenshots.

Comment: Just didn't think about copying. Is it against some rule? I can surely edit in that case.

Comment: No, it's not against any rule, but there's really no point in posting text as an image. Plus it takes more space, and is a link to an external resource (which may go away or not be available...)

Comment: Ok, just catched again and edited the question. That should fix it. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the exact problem, you can catch all exceptions as so:

```
try: 
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(myUrl['link'],str(count)+'.jpg')
except URLError as e:
    print(e.reason)
except KeyboardInterrupt as ki:
    raise ki
except:
    print("Unknown Error")
```

Comment: Don't use raw `except` - it'll swallow things that aren't exceptions (like `KeyboardInterrupt`). Use `except Exception` instead.

Comment: Yeah, raw `except` works, but if you edit with this better answer I will mark it and close the case. :)